# URL rewriting: addon domains, subdomains, and directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, bluehost

Say I have `domain.com` and `addon.com`. My hosting provider is Bluehost. `domain.com` is the primary domain (hosted in `public_html`) and `addon.com` is an addon domain (hosted in `public_html/addon`). I'd like to make the following redirects:

- `http://domain.com/addon/*` → `http://addon.com/*`
- `http://addon.domain.com/*` → `http://addon.com/*`

For reference, both `public_html/.htaccess` and `public_html/addon/.htaccess` have working rules for removing the `www` prefix:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301]
```

How do I go about adding the other redirects in a way that will play nice with these rules?

Comment: Deleted my answer due to updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Place these 2 rules in your public_html/.htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(addon)/(.*)$ http://$1.com/$2 [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(addon)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.com/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Neither has any effect. These ought to work, and I’d already tried essentially the same thing, but to no avail.

Comment: Have already tested them on my hosts and found them to be working fine. I would suggest you to provide your access.log file snippets as well when you test it and if possible enable RewriteLog as well.